# How do you create a second dynamic dependant dropdown in Google Sheets App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have started a Google Sheet which has 4 dropdowns. Dropdowns 2, 3 and 4 all depend on the selection in dropdown 1. I have got dropdown 2 working but can't work out the code in App Script Editor for dropdowns 3 and 4.

This is my sheet titled 'Dropdown Lists':

[image: Dropdown List]

Row 1 is in dropdown 1 (Column C of the 'Event/Incidents' Sheet)

Rows 4 to 10 are in dropdown 2 (Column D of the 'Event/Incidents' Sheet)

Rows 15 to the end row are in dropdowns 3 (Column E of the 'Event/Incidents' Sheet) & also in dropdown 4 (Column F of the 'Event/Incidents' Sheet)
This is the 'Events/Incidents' Sheet.

[image: Events/Incidents]

I have the following code which works for dropdown 2 (Column D of the 'Events/Incidents' Sheet) only:

[image: App Script Code]

Would really appreciate help with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to adapt your script and create additional dropdown menus, you need to

- create additional validation rules
- with adjusted validation ranges
- adjust the offset according to the position where the dropdown menu shall be inserted.

**Sample:**

```
      var validationRange2=datass.getRange(15,baseIndex,datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule2=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange2).build()
      activeCell.offset(0,2).setDataValidation(validationRule2);
```

The full code would be:

```
function onEdit() {
 var tablists="Dropdown Lists";
  var tabValidation="Events/Incidents";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tablists);
  var activeCell=ss.getActiveCell();
  if(activeCell.getColumn()==3&&activeCell.getRow()>1&&ss.getSheetName()==tabValidation){
    activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    var base=datass.getRange(2,1,1,5).getValues();
    var baseIndex=base[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue())+1;
    Logger.log(baseIndex);
    if(baseIndex!=0){
      var validationRange=datass.getRange(3,baseIndex,10);
      var validationRule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build()
      activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

      var validationRange2=datass.getRange(15,baseIndex,datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule2=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange2).build()
      activeCell.offset(0,2).setDataValidation(validationRule2);
      activeCell.offset(0,3).setDataValidation(validationRule2);

    }
  }
}
```

To obtain a better understanding of the code, please refer to the Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) and [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions)